# Create object literal with keys that aren’t valid identifiers

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In my object literals, I would like to create keys that would not be valid identifiers in order to generate a JSON file like the one in the picture, using JavaScript.

Is it possible to create the object like the following?

```js
var objet = {
  targets: [
    new Stage(),
    {
      isStage: false,
      name: "Sprite1",
      blocks: {
        o7d.+f~]6/Bs|=|c/F(=: "Hello"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

This is what the JSON file looks like:

[image: JSON file]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ES6 feature objet litteral dynamic key:

```
const illegalKey = 'o7d.+f~]6/Bs|=|c/F(=';
...
blocks: {
    [illegalKey]: "Hello"
}
```

Or just:

```
blocks: {
    'o7d.+f~]6/Bs|=|c/F(=': "Hello"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

```js
const data = {
  blocks: {
    "o7d.+f~]6/Bs|=|c/F(=": "Hello"
  }
}

console.log(data)
```

But please be careful what exactly you are doing, because you loose readability with this keys naming.

Answer (score 0):

For understanding purpose, I have picked a sub-set of the object.

You can try following

```js
var blocks = {
  "o7d.+f~]6/Bs|=|c/F(=": "Hello" // surround key with quotes
};

console.log(blocks["o7d.+f~]6/Bs|=|c/F(="]); // use bracket notation to fetch
```